# My personal launchagents have stopped working in MacOS Ventura. Any ideas?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have a number of launch agents I've written over the years to automate some simple tasks, like rsyncing my music and photos from my laptop to my NAS. Recently I've noticed that they have stopped running daily like they used to. Instead, they're only running when I log in. Here's a sample launchagent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mwheinz.backup_photos</string>
    <key>Program</key>
      <string>/Users/michaelheinz/bin/backup_photos</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

When I run them with "debug" it says they are configured to run "at launch":

```
~ » sudo launchctl debug gui/501/com.mwheinz.backup_books
Password:
Service configured for next launch.
```

Any suggestions? One thing I've noticed is that launchd now insists I refer to my agents as "gui/501/<label>" instead of just "<label>".

Comment: Are you sure your energy saving settings did not change. Could it be there your computer is sleeping during the scheduled time.

Comment: Also check if this could an issue: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/351632/is-there-command-to-grant-full-disk-access-for-specific-application

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's almost certainly not full disk access because the scripts run correctly when I log in. The point about sleeping is a good one. I'm honestly not sure  how launchd handles tasks that should run when the laptop is sleeping. I assumed they ran the next time the laptop woke up.

Comment: Their manual should have it. That is exactly what I remembered; primary reason I switched from crontab to launchd. If computer was sleeping at the scheduled time, it runs as soon as it wakes up. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement; @supertech, I figured it out. The problem was completely different than I thought. At some point this syntax:

    <key>Program</key>

    <string>/Users/michaelheinz/bin/backup_books</string>

became this syntax:


    <key>ProgramArguments</key>

    <array>

      <string>/Users/michaelheinz/bin/backup_books</string>

    </array>

    <key>StartInterval</key>
```
I guess ventura finally stopped supporting the old syntax...

Comment: (and I give up trying to paste code into this comment... :-P )

Answer (score 1):

Okay - I figured it out. The problem for me was that the syntax for the plists changed at some point. This syntax:

```
<key>Program</key>
<string>/Users/michaelheinz/bin/backup_books</string>
```

became this syntax:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
  <string>/Users/michaelheinz/bin/backup_books</string>
</array>
```

I changed all my plists and they started working again.

Comment: Good catch. I am glad you have solved the problem.